# Jolt generating null while converting map to list

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I want to remove null values from the transformed JSON using Jolt spec for the example below:

**JSON input**

```
{
  "ratings": {
    "primary": 5,
    "quality": 4,
    "design": 5
  }
}
```

**Jolt spec**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ratings": {
        "primary": "primary1",
        "*": {
          // #2 means go three levels up the tree (count from 0),
          //  and ask the "ratings" node, how many of it's
          //  children have been matched.
          //
          // This allows us to put the Name and the Value into
          //  the same object in the Ratings array.
          "$": "Ratings[#2].Name",
          "@": "Ratings[#2].Value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output**

```
{
  "primary1" : 5,
  "Ratings" : [ null, {
    "Name" : "quality",
    "Value" : 4
  }, {
    "Name" : "design",
    "Value" : 5
  } ]
}
```

In the output first element of the "Rating" array is `null`, I want to avoid it from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 keys in the `ratings` object now. So when you ask it about how many of its children have been matched. its return **3**.

So you can separate `primary` from the `ratings` object. and then using another  `shift` operation and then asking the `ratings` node with `#2`, how many of its children have been matched. its return **2**.

In this case, you can prevent of `null` that is produced from `primary`.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ratings": {
        "primary": "primary1",
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "ratings": {
        "*": {
          // #2 means go three levels up the tree (count from 0),
          //  and ask the "ratings" node, how many of it's
          //  children have been matched.
          //
          // This allows us to put the Name and the Value into
          //  the same object in the Ratings array.
          "$": "Ratings[#2].Name",
          "@": "Ratings[#2].Value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Note: If you changed your input like this.**

```json
{
  "ratings": {
    "quality": 4,
    "design": 5,
    "primary": 5
  }
}
```

Your jolt spec working correctly.

Note that you should know when you use `[#2]`, you are using the index of object keys. like an array. So when you change the input like above, `null` is the last value and **jolt prevents it**.